# is it more correct to say an " at home" service or should I say an "at-home" service?

Tags: grammaticality

I have a company that provides services in the patients' own home.  When writing about it do I say "it's an at home service" or do I say an "at-home service"?  I feel perhaps the hyphen makes it easier to read and understand.

Comment: In my experience it's either *HOME SERVICE* or *HOME SERVICES* without the preposition.

Comment: @RonaldSole - Those work; also "in-home services."

Answer (score 2):

If you must make that choice then it’s an ‘at-home service’.

‘A service at home’ would describe how, or in this case where the service was provided.

‘An at-home service’ would describe the kind of service provided. The fact that here, ‘at-home’ appears to describe how or where the service was provided is slightly relevant in semantic terms; not at all in grammatical terms.

The hyphen makes it easier to read and understand in some circumstances; harder in others. Either way, it depends on the meaning intended.

If anyone really thinks dropping the preposition in favour of ‘home services’ changes anything, doubtless he will be able to explain how.

If anyone really thinks ‘in-home… ’  instead of ‘at-home services’ changes anything, doubtless he will be able to explain how.

Why would you care that you actually have a company which provides services… either in the patient’s own home or the patients’ own homes? The differences are between right and wrong, not matters of choice, so why should you give a rat’s whisker?

Having written that kind of sentence for thousands of clients over many years, I suggest you let go of the whole idea and start afresh.

If you want to say ‘I have a company which provides services in the patient’s own home’ then say so… only don’t use such an unnatural form. Say instead ‘… which provides services in the patient’s home’’

Please remember one of the worst problems choosing words for such situations is that written speech is very much not the same as… ‘real' speech, for which reason do not plan on paper what you want to say. Get two or three colleagues together and record a real conversation with no notes or other aids.

Talk for long enough - which might easily be half an hour or more - that the process of talking with a recorder running stops being a barrier. Having achieved that, you will be recording what you think of as natural speech describing the situation in which you actually find yourself, instead of artificial speech purporting to describe a situation with which you’re not truly comfortable.

If you doubt any of that, try listening a lot harder to the average TV commercial, and asking yourself how authentic either the words or the delivery f those words really sounds…

Answer (score -1):

"At-home" and "in-home" services are often used interchangeably, but they can carry slightly different connotations depending on context. Here's a breakdown of each:

At-home services: These are services that are typically provided at the client's residence but are not necessarily performed exclusively inside the home. They can include a wide range of services such as personal grooming (haircuts, manicures), home repairs, deliveries, and various forms of assistance. "At-home" implies convenience and accessibility, with the service being brought to the client's location.

In-home services: These services are specifically oriented toward activities or assistance provided within the confines of the home. They often involve personal care, healthcare, or professional services tailored to the individual's needs. Examples include home healthcare, therapy sessions, tutoring, and personal training. "In-home" emphasizes the idea of the service taking place entirely within the home environment.

In summary, while both terms generally refer to services provided within a residential setting, "at-home" services can encompass a broader range of activities that may extend beyond the home itself, whereas "in-home" services specifically refer to activities conducted entirely within the home